# nginx reverse proxy all requests to two upstream servers?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I need to adjust a nginx reverse proxy which used to front a single server to send all requests it receives to two different upstream servers.

I was thinking I could do it with the configuration below, but I wasn't sure if that would work and if I'd have to use re-write rules instead?

```
upstream  original_upstream  {
   server   <ip address>
}
upstream  new_upstream  {
  server   <ip address>
}

server {
  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://original_upstream;
  }
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://new_upstream;
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: So should the requests be load balanced between the upstream servers? Or are their any actual rules?

Comment: Actually, the goal would be to send all requests to both upstream servers and not be concerned with the acknowledgement on the `new_upstream`

Comment: You want to send request to both upstream simultaneously? What will you do when they both answser? Any way, there was similar question w/o answer, so I think it's hardly possible with nginx. http://stackoverflow.com/q/22948017 http://stackoverflow.com/q/23654964

Answer (score 1):

define your upstream servers like

`upstream yourname {
    server <ip serverA>;
    server <ip serverB>;
}`

(use *weight* or *backup* in your upstream conf if needed)

and use this upstream within your location

`location / {
    proxy_pass http://yourname;
}`