# Is it possible to send requests on some routes to all servers connected to an Nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

We are setting up an API that will need to be "sleeping" during certain hours. Sometimes we would like to override that with a control signal like "start" and "stop". We have the API set up as 4 docker containers with Nodejs Hapi and nginx to do load balancing.

We'd want any control signals (`curl -X POST http://myapi.company.com/stop`) to go to **all** the upstream servers. Normal requests (e.g. `curl http://myapi.company.com/meta/tables`) should be load-balanced normally and sent to only one server.

Is this possible with nginx?

The possible duplicate question doesn't explain how to route *some* requests to all upstreams.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nginx reverse proxy all requests to two upstream servers?](http://serverfault.com/questions/605774/nginx-reverse-proxy-all-requests-to-two-upstream-servers)

Comment: That one didn't seem to address the sub-url portion of my question.

Comment: That would be addressed by two location blocks. Short answer: not possible as far as I know. Suggest a better solution is required.

Comment: You said it would be addressed by the two location blocks then said it's not possible. Which is it?

Comment: At a high level, I don't believe sending a request to two servers is possible, as per the linked question. If it was then I guess that the split between the two URLs would be controlled by two location blocks.

Comment: My approach to a problem like this would be to make a script on all nodes, which would send the request to all nodes. Then one could call this script via the LB.